# Finishing a HttpServletResponse but continue processing

Tags: java, http, servlets, comet

I have a situation that seems to fit the Async Servlet 3.0 / Comet situation but all I need to do is return a 200 response code (or other) after accepting the incoming parameters.

Is there a way for a HttpServlet to complete the http request/response handshake and yet continue processing?

Something like...

```
doPost( req, response ) {
   // verify input params...
   response.setStatus( SC_OK );
   response.close();
   // execute long query
}
```

EDIT: Looking at the javax.servlet package - the proper phrasing to my question is

How do I commit a response?

as in Servlet.isCommitted()

Comment: "Committed" means some part of the response stream has already been sent to the client. It can't be taken back or modified. It can happen as soon as you set a header or write to the response, in theory, but usually the container buffers so it happens a bit later.

This is not relevant to you, I think. Don't close the response streams. Just set status, launch a thread as per other answers, let doPost() finish.

Comment: I tried to use response.sendError( SC_OK ) but it still did not flush the response to the requestor. It appears that the only way to close a servlet request is to return from a doPost().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I've handled this situation:

1. When the app starts up, create an [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)` (there are other types of executors, but I suggest starting with this one)
2. In `doPost()`, create an instance of [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) which will perform the desired processing - your task - and submit it to the `ExecutorService` like so: `executor.execute(task)`
3. Finally, you should return the HTTP Status [`202 Accepted`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.3), and, if possible, a `Location` header indicating where a client will be able to check up on the status of the processing.

I **highly** recommend you read [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/), it's a fantastic and very practical book.

Comment: While I agree with all the responses, this one has the least amount of complexity involved. Thanks to pajton, beny23 and avi for your input.

Comment: how do I do this, if I want to use executor.submit() instead of .execute? I want to use .submit so that I can get hold of "futures" and know when all the tasks have completed (based on which I have to do certain processing?).

Answer (score 3):

You can continue processing in a separate Thread.

The response is commited once you return from `doPost()` method.

Comment: I'm running into the URL Fetch service 5 sec timeout on perfectly good requests originating from a Google app engine. There is no need for the App Engine Requestor to block waiting for OK response from something that may take a very long time to complete processing.

Answer (score 3):

On possibility for your servlet to accept a request for processing in the background, is for the servlet to hand off processing to a separate thread which then executes in the background.

Using Spring, you can invoke a separate Thread using the a [TaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor). The advantage of using spring over standard JDK 5 `java.util.concurrent.Executor` is that if you're on application servers that need to use managed threads (IBM websphere or Oracle weblogic), you can use the `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` to hook into the CommonJ work managers.

Another alternative would be to move the long query logic into a Message Driven Bean or Message Driven POJO ([Spring JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html) can help here) and let the servlet simply post a message on a JMS queue. That would have the advantage that should the load on your web container become too great because of your long running query, you could easily move the MDB onto a different (dedicated) system.

Answer (score 0):

This example can help

```
void doPost(){
    // do something
   final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      executor.execute(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              // processing after response
          }
      });}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: It's better not to instantiate an ExecutorService every time the servlet gets a request or else you'll start creating a lot of threads that never die, at least per the newSingleThreadExecutor() documentation.