# Java - HttpServlet: When is the response sent to the client?

Tags: java, httpresponse

I was little experimenting with some HttpServlet stuff to understand it better. I wanted to build the scenario that a request is incoming and I need to send the response accordingly and as fast as possible and to do later some more work within the servlet. From my current understanding, the response should only be send to the client when the doGet or doPost method was returned. But from my example, the response is already sent back to the client within the processing of the commands in the servlet. So it is already returned when I was not expecting it to be.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayHeader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sw);
        //TODO most be implemented SynchronizedStatusCodeDimo
        out.println("StatusCode=0");
        out.println("StatusText=Accepted");
        out.println("paymentType=PaymentXY");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(sw.toString());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayHeader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } }
```

What is happening here, via Firebug I see that I already received the response generated after    510ms. I thought I would need more then 1500ms because of the sleeps. My understanding was based on this post here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367650/finishing-a-httpservletresponse-but-continue-processing)

Comment: What's the problem here? That flush() flushes? Or that close() closes? Why is this such a surprise?

Comment: Can we not spon request2 from the client after a success callback for request1. and request 2 can do the further processing based on request1 response..

Comment: Yes maybe there is no problem at all, I got it only wrong in the first place and was expecting the response after everything done in the Servlet (so when the doGet/doPost was returned), not like here in the middle of processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HttpServletResponse` will be controlled by your servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty etc.) .

If you write into the `response` the servlet container automatically flush the `response` after a defined buffer size (e.g Tomcat after 9000 byte). Usually you can configure it (in Tomcat with the parameter `socketBuffer`).
This is the way it works, if you do not control it by yourself.

In your case, you control the response by your self and after you call `response.flush()` the response will be send to the client.
If you had writte more the 9000 Byte (in Tomcat), the response will be send automatically (in the middle of it all).

(excuse my bad english)

Comment: Thanks. But out.close() forces the response to be sent in my example. When I remove the out.close() line and have only out.flush() the response is sent after 1500ms, so both sleeps are processed before the response is sent.

Comment: This is not correct. In your first case the answer starts after round about 500ms (after the out.flush()) and it also finished after 500ms because you close the stream. In the second the server starts the response after 500ms (after out.flush()), but the response ends after 1500ms because the servlet container close the stream after it all. You should see this in the firebug

Comment: I understand, it makes totally sense now. Thanks.